# unsorted array, find the next greater element for every element, else print -1

Tags: c++, algorithm, for-loop, vector, max

the requirement is a little bit complicated
let's say we have an unsorted array, for example: {12, 72, 93, 0, 24, 56, 102}

if we have an odd position, we have to look for the next greater element in his right, let's say we take v[1] = 12, the nge for '12' is 24;

but if we have an even position, we have to look for the next greater element in his left, let's say we take v[2] = 72, there s no number who s greater than '72', so we will print '-1'; let's take another example, v[4] = 0, the nge for '0' is 12;

the output should be: 24 -1 102 12 56 72 -1

i tried to solve this in c++:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int CONST = 10000;
    int n, v[CONST];
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        cin >> v[i];
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        int next = -1;
        if (i % 2 != 0) {   
            for (int j = i + 1; j <= n; j++) {
                if (v[j] > v[i]) {
                    next = v[j];
                    break;
                }
            }
            cout << next << " ";
        }
        else {                
            for (int k = 1; k <= i - 1; k++) {
                if (v[k] > v[i]) {
                    next = v[k];
                    break;
                }
            }
            cout << next << " ";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

firstly, i think that i have to sort the array and after that to use binary search for finding the next greater element

Comment: Your output depends on the unsorted relative positions of the elements. I usually default to sorting containers even when the benefit isn't obvious - so it's strange for me here to say "DON'T SORT THAT CONTAINER!"

Comment: @alexander s Indices in arrays in C++ start from 0. So the first element of an array has an even position.:)

Comment: @vlad as their problem and examples are worded, indices start at 1.

Comment: @JohnFilleau Nevertheless in the program indices shall start from 0.

Comment: @vlad I agree, but they're taking that into account by ignoring index 0 entirely in their array.

Comment: Your search for the "next greater" breaks when it finds the next one larger than. You need to go through all (no `break`) to find the one with the min difference.

Comment: There are some clever optimizations you can make on this problem, but just do the naive solution to start. Do a linear search on the appropriate range (all values to the left or right) and find the smallest number that is larger than your current value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70408459/how-can-i-efficiently-find-distances-from-each-value-to-the-next-lower-higher-va

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters instead of the array it is much better to declare an object of the type `std::vector<int>`.

Pay attention to that indices in C++ start from `0`.

In this if statement

```
            if (v[j] > v[i]) {
                next = v[j];
                break;
            }
```

you are exiting the loop as soon as the first element greater than the current is found. It is evident that this approach is wrong.

I can suggest the following solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    size_t n = 0;

    std::cin >> n;

    v.resize( n );

    for (auto &item : v)
    {
        std::cin >> item;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0, n = v.size(); i < n; i++)
    {
        size_t next = i;

        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            for (size_t j = i + 1; j != n; ++j)
            {
                if (v[i] < v[j] && ( next == i || v[j] < v[next] ))
                {
                    next = j;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (size_t j = i; j-- != 0; )
            {
                if (v[i] < v[j] && ( next == i || v[j] < v[next] ))
                {
                    next = j;
                }
            }
         }

         std::cout << ( next != i ? v[next] : -1 ) << ' ';
    }
}
```

The program output might look like

```
7
12 72 93 0 24 56 102
24 -1 102 12 56 72 -1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something **simple yet not very efficient** (e.g. O(n) space complexity -vector copy- and O(nlogn) time complexity -sort plus search- instead of an O(n) for a linear search), this is an option:

- `next_greater` checks if `pos` is even or odd, creates a couple of iterators `first` and `last`, and calls a templated `next_greater` with those iterators and the value to compare against, `n`.
- a templated `next_greater` sorts [`first`, `last`) and then uses upper_bound to return the first element that is greater than `n`.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/affYTqv6q)

```cpp
#include <algorithm>  // upper_bound
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <utility>  // pair
#include <vector>

template <typename InputIt, typename T>
T next_greater(InputIt first, InputIt last, T n)
{
    std::sort(first, last);
    auto it{ std::upper_bound(first, last, n) };
    if (it == last) { return -1; }
    return *it;
}

int next_greater(std::vector<int> v, size_t pos)
{
    using it = std::vector<int>::iterator;
    using pair_it = std::pair<it, it>;

    auto [first, last] { (pos % 2 == 1)
        ? pair_it{ std::begin(v), std::begin(v) + pos }  // [begin, pos)
        : pair_it{ std::begin(v) + pos + 1, std::end(v) }  // [pos + 1, end)
    };
    return next_greater(first, last, v[pos]);  
}

int main()
{
    const std::vector<int> v{12, 72, 93, 0, 24, 56, 102};
    std::cout << "Next greater for i(n):\n";
    for (size_t i{0}; i < v.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "\t" << i << "(" << v[i] << "): " << next_greater(v, i) << "\n";
    }
}

// Outputs:
//
//   Next greater for i(n):
//      0(12): 24
//      1(72): -1
//      2(93): 102
//      3(0): 12
//      4(24): 56
//      5(56): 72
//      6(102): -1
```